# 10mA inverting charge pump

Tags: voltage, inverter, charge, negative

[image]

I have limited knowledge of switch caps voltage inverters and charge pumps.

I need to generate -2.5V in my system capable of sourcing about 7.5mA.
I have MCU and two rails 3.3V and 5V.

So far, I simulated charge pump in arrangement similar to one above followed by LDO. From what I gathered charge pumps degrade the voltage under the load due to caps now being discharged and not fully “boosting” level and due to diode voltage drops.

Before I consider other approaches, I hope for some suggestions to what could be done to improve in order to get the current up without degrading the output level too much.

Schematic above is taken from: http://chrisgreenley.com/projects/charge-pump/

Comment: essentially, larger caps, and better diodes. also, where did you get a negative voltage LDO from?

Comment: In this design is lacking however I considered adding one to make the output steadier. If voltage under load would stay above threshold required.